# Android passing shuffled list between two classes

Tags: android, list, class

have another tough question:
i have two classes, both using one list

```
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.ac_pre, R.drawable.acc_pre,
        R.drawable.acd_pre, R.drawable.ach_pre,
        R.drawable.acs_pre, R.drawable.ad_pre,
        R.drawable.ah_pre, R.drawable.as_pre,
        R.drawable.dc_pre, R.drawable.dd_pre,
        R.drawable.dh_pre, R.drawable.ds_pre,
        R.drawable.fc_pre, R.drawable.fd_pre,
        R.drawable.fh_pre, R.drawable.fs_pre,
        R.drawable.jc_pre, R.drawable.jd_pre,
        R.drawable.jh_pre, R.drawable.js_pre,
        R.drawable.kc_pre, R.drawable.kd_pre,
        R.drawable.kh_pre, R.drawable.ks_pre,
        R.drawable.nc_pre, R.drawable.nd_pre,
        R.drawable.nh_pre, R.drawable.ns_pre,
        R.drawable.qc_pre, R.drawable.qd_pre,
        R.drawable.qh_pre, R.drawable.qs_pre,
        R.drawable.sec_pre, R.drawable.sed_pre,
        R.drawable.seh_pre, R.drawable.ses_pre,
        R.drawable.sic_pre, R.drawable.sid_pre,
        R.drawable.sih_pre, R.drawable.sis_pre,
        R.drawable.vc_pre, R.drawable.vd_pre,
        R.drawable.vh_pre, R.drawable.vs_pre,
        R.drawable.xc_pre, R.drawable.xd_pre,
        R.drawable.xh_pre, R.drawable.xs_pre,
        R.drawable.zc_pre, R.drawable.zd_pre,
        R.drawable.zh_pre, R.drawable.zs_pre
        };
```

which is shuffled in either of them, but both acessing the list (which should be shuffled)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid);

    Collections.shuffle(mTlist);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

this is in the Activity and the ImageAdapter is the other class.
But here comes the problem: Only in the class where the list is shuffeld, it is by the accesing, the other class (where the list isnt shuffled) the items are sorted like in mThumbIds (look at the top).

Any solution? It's better to use another methode? This is just the only one i found so far, that isnt to much of a code-mess.
Basiclly i need a random 10 items out of 52 in a list, accessible from all over my application.

Thankful for every anser! Greetings ueen

Comment: Did not understand what you're trying to ask. Are you shuffling the list in the beginning activity, but when you access it from this other class, it doesn't look shuffled? Where are you shuffling?

Comment: You understand it correctly; as you see is the shuffeling right at the beginning, before the other class (ImageAdapter) is called. "mischen", is a simple void shuffles by Collections.shuffle(mTlist);

Comment: edited the question, so its better to understand!

Comment: Could you paste the code of how you're declaring this list, and accessing the list? There's some problem with that part.

Comment: solved (see answer below)

Comment: Haha..I was going to suggest that method, but I wanted to make sure how you're accessing first :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make you list as static public variable in the main activity and access it from all other classes
put `static public Integer[] mThumbIds;` in you main activity (class ) and access it from other classes, if it is shuffled from any class other classes will read the new shuffled object

Comment: Awesome, thats it! Thank you!

Comment: if it helped you, would you please mark a tick on the answer to remove your question from unanswered section

Comment: ok. Any ideas on cutting the 42 itms below the top 10 of in a list (see original question)?

Comment: i don't get you question ,would you please start a new question explaining what you need